# formatting a form inside my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app with form inside of it. my css file is all ready. i just don't know how to apply the css form classes and ids also to the fields inside of my create action page where
my form_for lives?

```
 <%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div class="error_messages">
      <h2>Form is invalid</h2>
      <ul>
        <% for message in @user.errors.full_messages %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  </p>
  <p class="button"><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

my css styles for the form tag and for its fiels as below:

```
 id="phx-signup-form"
```

e-mail field css style:

```
 class="email-input"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<%= form_for @user, :html => { :id => 'phx-signup-form' } do |f| %>
```

and

```
<%= f.text_field :email, :class => 'email-input' %>
```

You can read more references on http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html

Comment: got it. thank you :) i will get back to you after i test it out.

Comment: You can see on your `users_controller.rb` on method `new` for that. Usually, it will contains `@user = User.new`. -- question changed.Good luck! :)

Comment: When i added the ids and classes, nothing happened to the styles look on the form, also the submit button won't work anymore, it shakes when i click it but no submission, when i remove the styles you did teach me how to add them, it works.

Comment: Yes, i saw the @user thank you its part of the code, because i am not used to such new coding to be used with css. i'm doing my best to make as i do it with html forms. because my page with html and css works just fine as i wanted to be. but with rails lots of modification needed and i am confused.

Comment: Take a look html tag using firebug or plain view source. I think with that modification you'll get proper id and class for your html tag.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start is the [Rails API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for).

```
form_for(@user, html: { id: 'phx-signup-form' })
```

should put you on the right path.

Comment: the css id in this case is the same as the application.css?

Answer (score 0):

Your form automatically takes id as `new_user` if your form is running as new form and takes id as `edit_user` if your form is running as edit form. So you use `id="new_user"` or `id="edit_user"` instead of `id="phx-signup-form"` in your css depending on condition.

For your form and   `<%= f.text_field :email, "", :class => 'email-input' %>` for emai field. Just try it. It may solve your problem.

Comment: now its more clear for me thank you.i wondering why rails forces me to use the way it wants me to style my html? for example in the above code i see i had to use a Hash instead of why i used to do inside of the html? i have no complains with rails programming only when it comes to templates and css. there is any other simpler solution to use my existing ids and classes names without having to change them? then why i use form_for why not use <form></form> ?

Comment: I tried it in a new blank project, i found out that my simple css won't apply to my form_for at all i followed this tutorial http://railscasts.com/episodes/234-simple-form?autoplay=true i don't have any error with coding, only no styles being applied, i double checked the files and nothing happened :(