# How to assign HTML id to elements and how apply JavaScript to them?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I developed a project but now I wants to apply JavaScript to project. Take an example of Login Form. In that I have to assign HTML id to text-fields but HOW? 
and how I can access the text-fields in js file?

```
    <% @page_title = 'Staff Area Login' -%>

    <%= form_for(:stuff, :url => {:action => 'send_login'}) do -%>

    <p>Username:  <%= text_field_tag('username', params[:username]) %></p>

    <p>Password: <%= password_field_tag('password') %></p>

    <%= submit_tag("Log in") %>

    <% end -%>
```

Comment: This link may help you. [link to this answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12189176/formatting-a-form-inside-my-rails-app/12189644#12189644

Comment: but can you tell me how to access this id in js file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the :html hash.

```
<%= text_field_tag('username', params[:username], :html => {:id => "username_field"}) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form automatically takes id as `new_staff` if your form is running as new form and takes id as `edit_staff` if your form is running as edit form.

Comment: is it same for Elements(text-field) also ? or else?

Comment: but elements takes staff_text_field_name where text_field_name is your text field like name. if your name of text field is name then it takes staff_name as id.

Answer (score 0):

nt a ruby person iam but as far as i when you create a `text-field` like that. Ids are already asssigned have a look [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_field_tag)
and if you wanna access a particular `text-field` by id then just use
`document.getElementById('ID');` OR `$('#ID')` latter uses jquery